# timeout in Batch after changing path is not working?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am new to cmd. I have created a file to create folders and sub folders. I have put some `timeout`. The first `timeout` is working but other time out is not working do not know why. Is it because of changing the `path`. I have checked line by line in CMD. In CMD it works fine.

Input:

```
timeout /t 5

@echo off
set path=C:\Users\bruce\Documents\Project-Gallary
cd %path%
@echo "Welcome master Bruce !"
@echo "Recommended Project Folder Name: G01-Global-Report/C01-Compliance"
echo %PATH%
timeout /t 10
@echo " *** Try not the put space in Folder Name"
set /p ProjectName="What is the project name? "
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\bruce\Desktop>timeout /t 5

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...
"Recommended Project Folder Name: G01-Global-Report/C01-Compliance"
C:\Users\bruce\Documents\Project-Gallary
'timeout' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
" *** Try not the put space in Folder Name"
What is the project name?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Big mistake, you are changing a system variable `PATH`

System variable path lists all the paths to executables, you changed it by setting `set path=C:\Users\bruce\Documents\Project-Gallary` and now your other cmd's are no longer found.

Try this version instead, first close all your `cmd.exe` windows to clear all `set` commands.

```
@echo off
set "mypath=C:\Users\bruce\Documents\Project-Gallary"
cd %mypath%
@echo "Welcome master Bruce !"
@echo "Recommended Project Folder Name: G01-Global-Report/C01-Compliance"
echo %PATH%
timeout /t 10
@echo " *** Try not the put space in Folder Name"
set /p ProjectName="What is the project name? "
```

*Edit*

Based on @npocmaka's comment. If you actually want to add the path to the system path variable then simply replace the `set path` line to:

```
set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\bruce\Documents\Project-Gallary"
```

Comment: But the OP could need the `PATH`. So `set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\bruce\Documents\Project-Gallary"` can be used.

Comment: @npocmaka, indeed yes, but I can tell by the `cd %path%` that _master Bruce_ purely wanted to create a default path to locate projects. I will add the option though. Thanks.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard I was trying to echo my new path of my directory by %PATH% which is a mistake now I understand. Over all I have better understanding now. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is yes, it is because you have changed, `path`.

The environment variable `%Path%` contains locations which are searched when a 'pathless' executable file is not located in the current working directory.

The system also holds another variable called `%PATHEXT%` which contains a list of executable file extensions which are suffixed to a file name, *(in that lists order)*, if a file without an extension is called and not found.

If you want to see the values of those two variables, open a command prompt and enter, `Set Path`.

When your script gets to the second `Timeout` command, it searches the current working directory for any file named `Timeout` and with any of the extensions listed in `%PATHEXT%`. If not found, it would similarly search each of the locations in `%Path%`, which in your case would be `C:\Users\bruce\Documents\Project-Gallary`; *(as `timeout` was not found you received the error message)*

The `Timeout` command is really `timeout.exe` which should be located in `\Windows\System32`. Had you not changed the `%Path%` variable that location, *(preceded by the system drive letter)*, was defined within the value of the `%Path%` environment variable and the appropriate executable file found.

Your solutions are therefore to avoid setting variables named `%Path%` or `%PATHEXT%` unless absolutely necessary, e.g. `Set "lPath=C:\Users\bruce\Documents\Project-Gallary"`. You could alternatively ignore that advice and use absolute paths with extensions, e.g. `C:\Windows\System32\timeout.exe /t 10`. Finally you could, if the script requires it, integrate a location, *(or extension)*, into those exiting semicolon delimited variable listings, e.g. `Set "Path=%Path%;C:\Users\bruce\Documents\Project-Gallary"`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for elaboration. Now I understand everything.